# where count sql statement

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have stored count(ProductQuantity) into a list. As each ProductID have different count(ProductQuantity), i am trying to retrieve the ProductID based on the count(ProductQuanity).

```
  For Each i In sumofpquantity()

    Dim sq As String = "SELECT ProductID From OrderDetail Where COUNT(ProductQuantity)= " & i & ""
        Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sq, connection12)
        Dim reading As SqlDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
        While reading.Read()

            list.Add(reading.GetInt32(reading.GetOrdinal("ProductID")))

        End While
        reading.Close()
    Next i
```

sumofpquantity() is the method to store the count(ProductQuanity)

What is the correct sql statement to retrieve the productid based on the count(ProductQuantity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want the records with a given quantity, then simply remove the `COUNT`:

```
Dim sq = "SELECT ProductID From OrderDetail Where ProductQuantity = " & i
```

`COUNT` is an aggregate-function. So you would need a `GROUP BY ProductID` for example. You cannot count something that is already a single numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `having` clause to search for a product with a specific number of occurances.  For example, this looks for products with 42 sales:

```
select  ProductID 
from    OrderDetail 
group by
        ProductID 
having  SUM(ProductQuantity) = 42
```

To pass the number 42 to the database, consider using a parameter:

```
Dim sq As String = _
    "select  ProductID" & _
    "from    OrderDetail" & _
    "group by" & _
    "        ProductID" & _
    "having  SUM(ProductQuantity) = @cnt"
Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sq, connection12)
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnt", 42);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a good practice to use paramaterized queries, like this:

```
Dim sq as String = "SELECT ProductID " & _
                   "FROM OrderDetail " & _
                   "WHERE ProductQuantity = @DesiredQuantity"
Dim cmd2 as SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sq, connection12)
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DesiredQuantity", i)
```

With this query, SQL looks for products with ProductQuantity = @DesiredQuantity, and @DesiredQuantity is assigned the value of the variable i.  Parameters prevent SQL injection, amongst other potential problems.